# How many simultaneous website script requests can I handle with an 8 core, 16 thread processor before hurting performance?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, cpu, multicore

I have an 8 core, 16 thread processor. I have written a script that sends thousands of emails and it is a CPU intensive task. Initially I was executing my script just once from a web browser and waiting several minutes for the process to complete. Then I realized that I had an 8 core, 16 thread processor and what I did was to open multiple tabs in the web browser and execute the same script with the corresponding parameters from 4 different tabs. The thousands of emails were sent in 1/4 of the time that it would have taken if I had sent them all just from one tab all at once.

Sending 8000 emails by executing simultaneously my script 4 times from different tabs took 1/4 of the time that it would have taken to send 8000 by executing my script once and waiting until the process was completed. I took advantage of the fact that I had an 8 core, 16 thread processor. How many times can I run my script in parallel to expedite the process even more? If I could run it 16 times simultaneously, that would take 1/16 of the time! Is that what a 16 thread processor allows me to do? Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MartinJames I am trying to have the theory right before trying it because I do not want to exhaust my server capacity and do unintended things such as slowing down the website or things like that. So I have not tried it. I want to have good theory before taking this to practice.

Comment: OK, well, in that case, you should start assembling the necessary data: CPU, network, disk, RAM etc usage numbers on your client and server.  You can develop a spreadsheet to create a model of your whole system, analyse all the data and come to some conclusion that may, or may not reflect real operations...... or you could just try it.

Comment: @MartinJames Network, disk, RAM, etc. remain constants. I already proved that running my script simultaneously 4 times with a load of 2000 emails each (8000 in total) is faster than running the script once with a load of 8000 emails. I assume running my script simultaneously 8 times with a load of 1000 emails each (8000 in total) is even faster than the other two scenarios I tried. Then I can try running my script simultaneously 16 times with a load of 500 emails each (8000 in total). In wanted to get theory right before experimenting with the real server.

Comment: @MartinJames Exactly what I was trying to avoid, to take my website down for a moment while running experiments, but I did run the experiments, unfortunately the site went down for like a minute but I discovered what I needed to know. I will write it as an answer to my own question in case this can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I executed the script 8 times simultaneously from different tabs in the web browser. Each tab was configured in the parameters to send 2000 emails so that 2000 emails * 8 tabs = 16000 emails sent simultaneously by executing the same script 8 times. My rationale was that the 8 core, 16 thread processor that I have should be able to handle that and send the 16000 emails faster than if I were sending them all by executing my script a single time.

From the logs, only 5 of the 8 executions could run at the same time.  When one of the first 5 finished, the sixth started.  When the other of the first 5 finished, the seventh and eighth started.  So, at least I know not to run more than 4.  With 5 running, I sent 10,000 emails in 463 seconds.

My script works in such a way that every 100 emails sent successfully, I record the increment in the database.

The website went down when I had this in the database:

```
`emails`.`id`: 35 --> `emails`.`sent`=1300
`emails`.`id`: 34 --> `emails`.`sent`=1300
`emails`.`id`: 33 --> `emails`.`sent`=1400
`emails`.`id`: 32 --> `emails`.`sent`=1400
`emails`.`id`: 31 --> `emails`.`sent`=1400
```

When the website was back again, the first thing that I saw was:

```
`emails`.`id`: 38 --> `emails`.`sent`=200
`emails`.`id`: 37 --> `emails`.`sent`=200
`emails`.`id`: 36 --> `emails`.`sent`=300
`emails`.`id`: 35 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 34 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 33 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 32 --> `emails`.`sent`=2001
`emails`.`id`: 31 --> `emails`.`sent`=2001
```

At the end, I had all ~8000 emails sent successfully:

```
`emails`.`id`: 38 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 37 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 36 --> `emails`.`sent`=1999
`emails`.`id`: 35 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 34 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 33 --> `emails`.`sent`=2000
`emails`.`id`: 32 --> `emails`.`sent`=2001
`emails`.`id`: 31 --> `emails`.`sent`=2001
```